# Search date from SQL database from longer than one year ago

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Database varchar field which is called `date_finish`. This field has been setup as a varchar(50). The format of the date is set out like this: 07/06/2017 dd/mm/yyyy.

I'm trying to search the database for all dates over 1 year old using this statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, date_finish, 103) AS DB_DATE, booking_code, cust_id, status
FROM repair_details
WHERE (date_finish > DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY DB_DATE
```

There are some fields that are blank, cust_id is 0 and status aren't complete, so I added:

```
(date_finish <> '') AND (status = 'COMPLETE') AND (cust_id <> '0')
```

to the above statement.

In all cases I get an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a date using an explicit format:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, date_finish, 103) > DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE())
```

Obviously, this gets dates *since* one year ago -- based on your code.  If you want older dates, then use `<` rather than `>`.

Then, fix the data!  You should be storing date/time values using proper types.  One method is:

```
update repair_details
    set date_finish = CONVERT(date, date_finish, 103);  -- sets to default date format on system

alter repair_details alter date_finish date;
```

Comment: I didn't write the original data so i'm not sure why it's in varchar. I added it using the explicit format but it didn't work, it show all data up to this date not over 1 year ago

Comment: This should show only rows where `date_finish` is within the last year -- which appears to be the subject of this question.  Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: The question asks "from longer than one year ago"

Comment: @RickKap . . . The code and the question are inconsistent.  I did clarify the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done the date conversion in the WHERE clause - it is comparing a string to a date there.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because, when the column `date_finish` appears to be null. As such, you need to have a condition:

```
 ((date_finish  IS NOT NULL ) AND 
  (date_finish  <> ''       )     ) AND 
 (status        = 'COMPLETE'      ) AND 
 (cust_id       <> '0'            )
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but it's not showing data from over a year ago, it's showing data from 2018

Comment: @RickKap, my answer was pointing to resolve the error condition, which was what you were complaining about. Am I wrong?